# Force MatTable to render new rows

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have the following Angular component:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {ChromeDataService} from "../../../../shared/services/events";


export interface Element {
  position: number;
  eventName: string;
  elementId: string;
  elementClass: string;
  location: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
})

@Inject(ChromeDataService)
export class TableBasicExample {

  displayedColumns = ['position', 'eventName', 'elementId', 'elementClass', 'url'];
  ELEMENT_DATA: Array<Element> = [{
    position: 1,
    eventName: 'click',
    elementId: 'foobar',
    elementClass: 'foobarclass',
    location: 'yahoo.com'
  }];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  constructor(private data:ChromeDataService){

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log('events list component ngOnInit called.');

    const self = this;
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(m => {
      console.log('adding message to array11: ', m);
      self.ELEMENT_DATA.push(m as any);
    })

  }
}
```

I created an initial row in the table, and that has rendered fine. But when I call:

```
self.ELEMENT_DATA.push(m as any);
```

no new rows are added to the table. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to call something to force an update after pushing to the array? Or perhaps the array is copied when it's passed to the MatTable constructor, so maybe I need to call a method on the table instance?

I tried that, by doing this instead:

```
 this.dataSource.data.push(m as any);
```

but that didn't do anything either

Comment: I think you should call `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);` after adding to ELEMENT_DATA

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign newly updated data to `datasource.data` as below to render on UI. Add below after you pushing data to `self.ELEMENT_DATA`.

```
self.ELEMENT_DATA.push(m as any);
self.datasource.data = self.ELEMENT_DATA;
```